# Error target in makefile

Tags: makefile

This is my makefile:

```
.SILENT:
latexargs = -output-directory=temp -interaction=batchmode -file-line-error-style
thesis: mktemp
    latex $(latexargs) thesis || make errors
    bibtex -terse temp/A || make errors
    bibtex -terse temp/B || make errors
    latex $(latexargs) thesis || make errors
    pdflatex $(latexargs) thesis || make errors
    cat temp/thesis.pdf > thesis.pdf

diff: mktemp
    latex $(latexargs) thesis-diff || make errors
    bibtex temp/A || make errors
    bibtex temp/B || make errors
    latex $(latexargs) thesis-diff || make errors
    pdflatex $(latexargs) thesis-diff || make errors
    rm thesis-diff.tex

clean:
    test -e temp
    rm -f temp/*

mktemp:
    mkdir -p temp

errors:
    grep  ":[^:]*:" temp/thesis.log
    false
```

Is there no better way to run something if a command exits with a non zero code?

I have looked at the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) but could not find any special targets for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to set a flag so that any and all errors in recipes will trigger a certain action, but this is a little cleaner than what you have:

```
reportError = (grep  ":[^:]*:" temp/thesis.log && false)

thesis: mktemp
    latex $(latexargs) thesis || $(reportError)
    bibtex -terse temp/A || $(reportError)
    ...
```

Comment: true dat. This way I don't invoke a subshell. Thanks. I won't accept it though, I have a hard time believing such a powerful system doesn't have a way to do try-catch-finally procedure.